# How to host Django Channels (ASGI) with amazon_ec2?

Tags: django, amazon-ec2

The REST endpoints work completely fine, but the WS endpoints aren’t even registered as WS connection attempts. When I connect to wss://lms-backend-wiomf.ondigitalocean.app/ws/teacher/, it shows

```
[lms-backend] [2021-07-05 03:51:44] Not Found: /ws/teacher/
[lms-backend] [2021-07-05 03:51:44] 10.244.59.39 - - [05/Jul/2021:03:51:44 +0000] "GET /ws/teacher/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2560 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
```

how can I successfully  host my asgi application on aws-ec2 any one plz help

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the Gunicorn application server paired with `Uvicorn`, an ASGI implementation, to interface with your applications asynchronously. You have to then set up `Nginx` to reverse proxy to `Gunicorn`, hat giving you access to its security and performance features to serve your apps.

```
pip install uvicorn
```

I am assuming your Django project is running perfectly with `python manage.py runserver` command.
So let's check  Gunicorn’s Ability to Serve the Project-

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.asgi -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

**Note:** It is not required to use Gunicorn to run your ASGI application. To use only uvicorn, you would use the following command:

```
uvicorn myproject.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```

You have to change your `gunicorn.service` file, just follow the blew code-

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/root/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
      --access-logfile - \
      -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker \
      --workers 3 \
      --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
      myproject.asgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Don't forget to change `myproject` to your project name.
Then check your gunicron service is workking or not with the following command-

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
```

then,

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket
```

then test socket activation

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

Have a good day :)